# enter() and exit() with D3 nested selections

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a follow-up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22391008/creating-nested-html-structures-with-d3-js) question that I closed too hastily.

How/where would I put a `.exit()` or `.transition()` for the answers? In my original code, I'm saving the main chart in a variable (`questions_chart`), so I can say something like `questions_chart.exit().remove()`. However, if I put `.exit().remove()` after the `.text()` (last line in the code in Peter's answer), I get an error saying that `object array has no method 'exit'`

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this but will give it a shot...you would need to preserve the variable binding the data...like so:

```
var divs = d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
    .data(data.questions);

divs
    .enter().append("div") // this creates the question divs
    .text(function(d) { return d.value; })
    .selectAll("div")
    .data(function(d) { return d.answers; })
    .enter().append("div") // this creates the nested answer divs
    .text(function(d) { return d.value; });

divs.exit().remove();
```

I am assuming you don't need to remove just the divs that are answers. Hope this helps.

UPDATE: giving it a shot at dealing with questions and answers...

```
var divs = d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
    .data(data.questions);

var questionDivs = divs
    .enter().append("div") // this creates the question divs
    .text(function(d) { return d.value; });

divs.exit().remove();

var answerDivs = questionDivs
    .selectAll("div")
    .data(function(d) { return d.answers; });

answerDivs
    .enter().append("div") // this creates the nested answer divs
    .text(function(d) { return d.value; });

answerDivs.exit().remove();
```

Comment: Actually, that's what I'm trying to figure out what to do: how to also remove divs that are answers. The scenario is that questions can be added or deleted, and that individual answers for a particular question can also be added or deleted.

Comment: I am giving it a shot...again, not tested, so apologies if there are errors...and for the continuous editing...I am done now.